# keycloak container is restarting with an error docker-compose

Tags: hibernate, docker-compose, jboss, keycloak, keycloak-connect

```
  keycloak:
    image: gcr.io/my-private-1237028390/jboss/keycloak:latest ## (keycloak : v7)
    restart: always
    environment:
        DB_VENDOR: mariadb
        DB_ADDR: db
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: k3yc10ak
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: P@ssword
        KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT: 8080
        KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT: 8443
        JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL: JDBC_PING
        JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES: datasource_jndi_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,info_writer_sleep_time=500
    command:
      - "-b 0.0.0.0"
      - "-Dkeycloak.import=/home/peave_node/realm-export.json"     
    volumes:
      - ./realm-export.json:/home/pecave_node/pecave/realm-export.json
      - "/home/pecave_node/cert/:/etc/x509/https"      
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8780:8080       
    networks:
      - mydocknetwork
```

after docker-compose up -d
Then the connection with DB is successfully create and keycloak installation proceeds with all 96 tables created.. which seems perfect scenario of successful installation after that my container goes to restart again and again.. please any way to fix this

[image: Here the first error occured the end it goes into a restart loop I THINK THIS IS MAIN CAUSE]

I am using Keycloak 7 docker images  , and now it show this error [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the db_container make sure your db configuration are correct and mariaDB my.conf is executed while staring, if you my.cnf file permission are not rw then it will not run inside the container startup.

chmod 400 my.cnf